# First, Second, Third, and Finally

Tags: grammar, discourse-markers

Is it grammatically correct to sequence paragraphs using *First*, *Second*, *Third*, and *Finally*?

If not, is there a good word that replaces *Finally*? Starting a paragraph with *Final* doesn't sound correct. I could change all of the other words (e.g., *First* becomes *Firstly*), but I prefer the shorter versions. *Last* is the best replacement I can come up with, but it doesn't sound as fluid as *Finally*.

Forgive me for my painful-to-read example paragraphs. I'm not the most creative human being.

> First, I grabbed a spoon.
>
> Second, I ate the cereal.
>
> Third, I drank the milk.
>
> Finally, I tossed the bowl in the dish washer.

Comment: I get the feeling many speakers (Americans in particular) don't much like *firstly, secondly,... **lastly***, but if you're determined not to simply number the paragraphs *1, 2, 3, **4*** that might be the most *consistent* approach.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This [article](http://bizwritingtip.com/?p=1540) might help explain why some people prefer the short version. I have to question whether the preference is more prominent among Americans, but I can't find any useful information that points either way.

Comment: When I posted that comment half-an-hour ago, it really was just a feeling I had, based on comments some (mainly American) users have posted here on ELU in the past. But since you've questioned it, I just checked [this NGram, which seems to support what I said](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=firstly%2Clastly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirstly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clastly%3B%2Cc0). Toggle between US/UK corpuses, note both the shape of the charts and the left-hand "prevalence" scales, and I think you'll agree with me.

Comment: But [here's some advice](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-tymylKJss8C&pg=PA90&dq=firstly+secondly+lastly&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RDOOU7ufDMaM0AWD1YG4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=firstly%20secondly%20lastly&f=false) you may find useful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The difference in scales has me mostly convinced. It could be that British English writers are more prone to numbering their paragraphs than American English writers, but I find that unlikely. Thanks for the comparison.

Comment: I didn't think of that "explanation" - the mere fact that you *did* suggests you could get to be pretty good at mining NGrams/Google Books for information. On the other hand, I already knew the answer I "wanted", which is often a handicap in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your compliment is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, *first, second...finally* is fine, as is *...lastly*. And *firstly, secondly...finally/lastly* is also fine. I would probably refrain from using *?last* or **final*.

Note that the (most) traditional sequence is *first, secondly, thirdly...lastly*; don't be afraid of "inconsistencies" in idiom! See [my earlier answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/886/when-enumerating-motivations-is-it-correct-to-write-firstly-secondly-or) and *Fowler's Modern English Usage* (3rd edition).

The Oxford English Dictionary on *firstly*:

> Used only in enumerating heads, topics, etc. in discourse; and many writers prefer *first*, even though closely followed by *secondly, thirdly*, etc.

Burchfield in *Fowler's Modern English Usage* on *first*:

[image]

Comment: @Rusher: Firstly, I think we have to accept that you really are *just a failure at operating Google's ngram*. Obviously there are many other contexts besides numbering "bullet points" where only ***first*** can be used in the first place (there's one, for example). Mind you, even if you'd composed a truly representative NGram, I'm sure the ***-ly*** versions would be *relatively* uncommon. Nevertheless, I suspect Cerberus's "traditional" is reasonably accurate here.

Comment: @Rusher: ... ***Secondly,*** (! :) When I started writing, I did actually intend to make at least one or two more points - but there's a limit to what you can cram into a comment here. Also don't conflate ***my*** "feelings" and "suspicions" with ***Cerberus's*** text. He almost certainly has far more "formal knowledge" in such matters than me.

Comment: @Rusher: Perhaps the quotations I have added to my answer will convince you that it is indeed true. Statistics rarely help when you're researching *style*.

Comment: @Rusher: No apology needed. I did not give any references for that bit about *first, secondly, thirdly* at first because it was only a note, but I guess it is better now.

Comment: First, since the question is really about rhetoric rather than grammar, I would say that you absolutely _should_ worry about inconsistencies. Parallelism is one of the easiest ways to make content easier to read and absorb. And B, (see? it's jarring.) I disagree with your advice not to use "last". It's just as fine to use "last" as it is to use "first".

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam: Inconsistencies *in idiom*.

Comment: @Cerberus Isn't this a cross-post? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/886/firstly-secondly-or-first-second

Comment: @Masoud: Similar answers were posted on both sites, but the questions were asked by different people.

Comment: De Quincey was expressing a personal opinion that should not be taken seriously and certainly not as an authority: his comment should not have made it into Fowlers. Nor should CEGL have used the anonymous "some people find it..." as it also implies  that some people **do not** find it objectionable and is thus worthless. ++ The OED gives the use predating De Quincey by some 200 Years:- a1475  (▸?a1430)    J. Lydgate tr. G. Deguileville Pilgrimage Life Man (Vitell.) l. 21575   Expowne fyrst-lyk my desyr. --
?1533   G. Du Wes Introductorie for to lerne Frenche sig. Eiv   Fyrstly, premierment.

Comment: @Greybeard: I'm not sure what point you are making here. It is a widely held opinion with ample supporting evidence. You or various other people may have a different opinion, which is fine. Just be aware of it.

Answer (score 15):

If you feel awkward starting paragraphs with *firstly*, *secondly* etc. consider the following expressions as suitable equivalents.

- *Initially* / *To begin with OR to start with* (less formal) = First(ly)
- *Then* / *next* / *after that* / *afterwards* = later
- *In addition* / *additionally* = Second(ly)
- *Furthermore* / *moreover* OR *What's more* (less formal) = Third(ly)
- ***In conclusion*** / **lastly** OR **in the end** (less formal)= Finally

> To start with, I grabbed a spoon.
> Then I took a bowl and filled it with cereal
> Next, I poured some milk into my bowl.
> Afterwards I began to eat my cereal and when I'd finished, I drank the milk.
> **In the end**, I tossed the bowl in the dishwasher.

Comment: Should I use comma after each of them? @Mari-Lou A

Comment: For example, could I use comma  after `afterwards` on your given example? @Mari-Lou A

Comment: @Alper you usually use a comma after these words if they begin a sentence, but with "then" and "afterwards" (UK)  or "afterward" (US) you need to be more careful. Look them up in a good dictionary that gives examples. The comma could go between *afterwards* and *I began* but I don't think it's essential.

Comment: I think this is the right approach, but maybe you need to  be more explicit about the fact that a **numerical** sequence isn't always called for.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A can we use "second" or "next" instead of second(ly) whether we have two items or more?

Comment: @A-friend you need to mention at least two things in order to use "second(ly)" or "next", so the answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

The following seem to fit into your example:

- Lastly...
- Last...
- And in the end...
- To finish...

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that what bothers you about "First, Second, Third, and Finally" may be an apparent lack of *[parallel structure](https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/grammar/parallel-structure.html)*: The first 3 items don't end it "ly" and the first three seem on the surface to be nouns or adjectives while the last is an adverb.

But don't pay too much attention to surface form alone.  If you check a quality dictionary, you'll find that all four words can be used as adverbs.  So there is no lack of parallel structure.

For example, in my print volume of *Random House Webster's College Dictionary* (2001), there are these definitions:

> **first.** Definition #9. *adv*. In the first place; firstly.
>
> **second.** Definition #21. *adv*. In the second place; secondly.
>
> **third.** Definition #11. *adv*. In the third place; thirdly.

If you're writing poetry, then you may want to pay more attention to the structural forms of the words in addition to the part of speech.  But for ordinary prose, matching the "grammatical form" (as opposed to the surface form) is perfectly fine:

> Every element of a parallel series must be a *functional* match...and
> serve the same *grammatical* function. (*Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th
> edition (print) section 5.212, p. 259, emphasis added)

> Express parallel ideas in parallel form. Adjectives should be
> paralleled by adjectives, nouns by nouns, infinitives by infinitives,
> subordinate clauses by subordinate clauses, etc. (*The Gregg Reference
> Manual*, 6th edition (print), section 1081, p. 215)