# Alternatives to "then", "next" (at the beginning of the phrase) in formal text (for Academic papers)

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, formality

I am writing an academic paper and, at a certain point, I want to write: "Firstly,... Then, ... Next, ... Lastly...."

However, "Then" and "Next" at the beginning of phrases sound like very INFORMAL English. I need FORMAL alternatives. What do you suggest/use?

I know this article suggesting "First... Second... Third... Lastly...":
[First, Second, Third, and Finally](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174847/first-second-third-and-finally)
But I already used this structure somewhere else in the text, so I want to avoid repetition.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the nature of the items being enumerated with these words? What determines the order: is it chronology, a logical argument, a ranking in order of importance? How long is the description of each of them in the paper? All of these affect how you might introduce each point. I don't necessarily read "Then" and "Next" as informal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Then: subsequently, in addition
Next: consequently
Finally: to conclude, to summarize

If your sentences and paragraphs are written in active voice, and they are tightly constructed, your reader will follow your sequence easily, without need for the linking words you asked about.

Comment: "Consequently" instead of "next" expresses an idea that following point results from the previous one. Would you have another suggestion?